# Install/Setup Tensorflow on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I am trying to install ***tensorflow*** on windows 10. I followed this [Install TensorFlow with GPU for Windows 10](http://blog.nitishmutha.com/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html) tutorial step-by-step. No error while I followed all the steps.

But when I comleted the entire process and tried to import tensorflow I got the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 62, in preload_check
>       ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\ctypes__init__.py", line 348, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>   OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in 
>       self_check.preload_check()
>     File "C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 70, in preload_check
>       % build_info.nvcuda_dll_name)
>   ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.

What am I missing? Also, please let me know if there is any other better way of installing tensorflow on windows, on Ubuntu it's way more simpler.

Comment: Check the following
1) Have you installed Nvidia drivers?
2) Have you installed CUDA 9.0 SDK?
3) Have you installed cuDNN 7.0?

Also, make sure the cuda/bin folder is in the path

Comment: After your comment I rechecked everything and It's all there but CUDA's version is 9.1, will it create a problem?

Comment: Yes. TF 1.5.0 *precompiled* package supports only CUDA 9.0, while TF, if compiled from source, supports CUDA 9.1. Installing CUDA 9.0 is a much much easier task

Comment: Okay. Thanks for reply. Let me go back and install 9.0, recheck again.